# How can I create orthopedic insole/slipsole by my own means?

Tags: feet, orthotics, footwear, bandaid-plaster-bandage

I want to try using orthopedic insole, but found them extremely expensive if one want to get an individual design for some pair of shoes. In my basic understanding it should not be difficult to create it by our own means.

Do you have any such experience? What are the materials I need to this (plaster?)?

Comment: This is not about a life hack, you are asking for medical advice. If you mess this up you can hurt yourself quite thoroughly.

Comment: @DougWatkins thanks for a comment. In my basic understanding the ortho soles just copy our foot "plate" landscape, thus we should create the basic plaster form, cut it to some pieces and glue them on some other "sole". http://www.nytimes.com/2006/06/22/fashion/thursdaystyles/22Fitness.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0

Comment: Medical hack, possibly affecting health of OP or others in a negative way

Comment: @holroy the Internet is full of crazy medical advices and hacks. I just asked if someone tried to create the insole himself.

Comment: If you are trying to address Plantar Fasciitis you can buy DIY insole kits from most decent pharmacies for a lot less than the custom orthotics that you mention.

Comment: If you have a pronation problem rather than plantar fasciitis, you need a specialist custom insole - there's a reason why podiatrists spend so long training - they know better than we do.